# Image cropping and transformation in Javascript - Scanning app

Tags: image, image-processing, computer-vision, javascript

I am looking for Javascript libraries that can help me do the following:

1.Given an image. Crop it using 4 coordinates points. (this may result in a non regular quadrilateral)

2.Transform the new image into a regular rectangle.

There is an [example here](http://s1.postimg.org/4gd1lhphb/example.jpg).

I've looking at libraries like JCrop (and many others), but as far as I can see it only crops using regular rectangles.

The libraries could either be for client or node.js.

Bonus points for a computer vision library that can do corner detection.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see the "transformation" just crops the image anyway.

So just first transform the 4 coordinates to a regular rectangle and then use a library like JCrop.

> Example: (each coordinate is x,y)

```
[left-up]   | [right-up]
[left-down] | [right-down]
```

> 4 coords:

```
22,11 | 45,13
25,56 | 47,62
```

> Rectangle:

```
25,13 | 45,13
25,56 | 45,56
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Do you know how to transform an image in JS? Any libraries?